# IIS 10 & IIS Express - MVC app - 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

So I feel like this has been asked lots, but none of the answers I have found solve my issue.

I have an old MVC 5 project, .NET Framework 4.5 that I am trying to run for the 1st time in ages.  Whether I run through Visual Studio 2017 or through IIS 10 - I get the same error:

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Things that have been suggested and that I have tried

1. Anonymous auth enabled, Windows Disabled (it uses forms authentication)
2. IIS_IUSRS has full access to the directory (I have even added everyone just to be sure)
3. It can serve static content from images
4. I have tried adding the following to the web.config

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

5. The machine I am running it on can run other .NET MVC applications totally fine
6. I tried to run it on a different server and I get the same error

I am pretty sure there is something funky in the web.config but I am at a loss.

Help please

Comment: What URL triggered that 403? You also need to reveal the complete error page.

Comment: Please review your IIS log or enable detailed error message. We need to find the sub-status code of 403 error. Most of time we will face 403.14 error which means your application is handled by incorrect handler. Then you need to find whether <handler>has been override in web.config. Anyway, please post the sub-status field first.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up questions.  I have ended up reverting to an earlier commit, re-doing all the Nuget packages and now its working, I cant spend any more time playing with the broken build.  Obviously some Nuget package updated and messed things up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the follow up questions.  I have ended up reverting to an earlier commit, re-doing all the Nuget packages and now its working, I cant spend any more time playing with the broken build.  Obviously some Nuget package updated and messed things up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same Access Denied error trying to run a new .NET Core or .NET 5.0 website created from Visual Studio templates. *My local hosting environment was not configured for either.*

Once I created the template using the same .NET version as my environment, the site launched without issue.